# Is there a Wordpress Plugin for friendly code highlighint & editing?

Tags: html, wordpress

I've seen various plugins that give the full editor code highlighting functionality, but what I really want is something that applies this to the standard post/page editor.

We have Visual and HTML, but HTML view is totally unformatted and horrible to work with.

Surely there must be something that can address this?

Cheers,

Chris.

Comment: take a look here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/syntax-highlighting-in-wordpress-html-editor?replies=4

Comment: Thanks! Found one that works perfectly on another link on that page, and it looks brand new from what I can see. It's called WP Editor and can be found here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-editor/

Answer (score 2):

Brand new plugin is available which does this perfectly.

It's called WP Editor and can be found here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-editor/

Thanks to janw above for the link.